# Django over-writing our DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: python, django, macos

I'm having some strange trouble with a DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and django.

In my (im using OSX) ~/.bash_profile I have the following:

```
export TEST=dir1
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=dir2
```

When I start IPython (from within a virtualenv) I can do this

```
import os
'TEST' in os.environ  (returns True)
'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH' in os.environ   (returns True)
```

when I try the exact same in ./manage.py shell, I get

```
import os
'TEST' in os.environ  (returns True)
'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH' in os.environ   (returns False)
```

I am completely lost as to what might be causing this.

Comment: Why do you need to set this?

Comment: I have a SWIG extension which loads a dynamic library object.